# addClass on each input validating wrong in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a syntax error - I'm trying to add a class of 'error' if the input fields are blank.  It's seems the error class is being applied even if the input fields have text, the logic looks correct to me.  Can someone please assist?

```
$('input').each(function() {
    if($(this).val() == "") {
        $("input").addClass("error");
       return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Initially they must have been left blank, that time the class is applied. But nothing happens after that. Did you forgot to apply class after text is entered ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `$(this)` to while invoking `.addClass()`,

```
$('input').each(function() {
    if($(this).val() == "") {
        $(this).addClass("error");
    }
});
```

Or the best approach would be using using `.filter()`,

```
$('input').filter(function(){ 
   return this.value.trim() === "";
}).addClass("error");
```

Answer (score 1):

you should `addClass` to `this`, but better use `toggleClass` to also remove error if input got filled:

```
$('input').each(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('error', this.value == "");
});
```